# How do I print out all 8 bytes of 8 byte variables and how can I apply the `&&` bit wise operator on them?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

How do I print out all 8 bytes of 8 byte variables and how can I apply the `&&` bit wise operator on them ?

```
int main(void)
{
     uint64_t a = 0x2345678987654321;
     uint64_t b = 0x2345678987654321;
     uint64_t c = 0x11111111;
     b= 0x2345678987654321 && 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00;
     printf("a is %llX b is %llX c is %llx" ,a, b, c);
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `&&` is a logical operator while `&` is bitwise operator.

Comment: You now have two answers. If any or all answered your question, please accept the one most fitting. You can also upvote any answer you like. This is the stackoverflow way to say "thank you for your time".

Answer (score 4):

The `&&` operator is a *logical* and. It yields a boolean (true/false, in C represented by an `int` value of `1`/`0` guaranteed) result iff both operands are non-zero. It also evaluates strictly left operand first and the right only iff the result depends on it (i.e. if the left operand is non-zero; this works correspondingly for a chain of identical logical operators).

You need the bit-wise `&` (and) operator which evaluates all (integer) operands:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>  // format-strings for stdint.h types

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t a = 0x2345678987654321U;
    uint64_t b = 0x2345678987654321U;
    uint64_t c = 0x11111111U;
    b = b & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00U;
    printf("a is %016" PRIx64 " b is %016" PRIx64 " c is %016" PRIx64, a, b, c);
}
```

Note I added `U` suffix to the constants to ensure they are unsigned. You might add a width suffix, but that is not required and actually quite useless, because `LL`, making the constant `long long` would not guarantee 64 bits (it could well be >64 bits). If you want constants with a specific type, cast them, e.g.:

```
#define U64_CONST ((uint64_t)0x123U)
```

An alternative way to get **at least** a 64 bit unsigned type:

```
#define U64_CONST UINT64_C(0x123U)
```

This macro will generate a `uint_least64_t` (see [`stdint.h](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20) for more). As always, enable warnings to let your compiler help you finding constants which do not fit into the given type.

For similar reasons, the correct [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) (see the link why I added `016`) and `scanf` format-specifiers for `stdint.h` types are in [`inttypes.h`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.8). Each is a macro with a string-literal containing the correct format-specifier for your platform. Use string-literal concatenation (two adjacent string-literals are combined to a single string-literal - note there is no operator in-between) to assemble the format-string.

**Note:** The above is - of course - also valid for types of other bit-sizes (and possible more important).

Comment: @paulr: Thanks for the edit. Just to let you know I did not DV your answer.

Comment: @PaulR: Well, you might be complaining, but this is read by quite some beginners. Don't you agree they should it learn the correct and most standard/portable way first? Once they learned, they should be able to know when to follow the rules and when you can "stretch" them a bit. This is much like driving a car: you first have to exactly follow the speed limit and later you know you can drive 10-20% faster sometimes.

Comment: Well very few code examples are perfect (e.g. you are missing `#include <stdio.h>` in your code above) - it's a matter of judgement as to what level of code quality is required to answer a specific question.

Comment: `ULL` will be *at least* 64 bits, so you could specify a 64-bit constant that way, with a `(uint64_t)` cast to be certain. But all these examples should be using `UINT64_C(val)`.

Comment: @BrettHale: Thanks for the input. To be true, I always forget about this macro. However, that will convert to `uint_least64_t` actually - for good reasons, as my cast will truncate any other type. I'll add that info.

Comment: Remember how `<stdint.h>` was going to make life easy? Ha!

Comment: @BrettHale: As an embedded developer, I actually think it does. At least if people finally stop using their hand-crafted `u8`, etc. OTOH, I do not use `printf`, etc. in my projects very often. But I agree, I'd prefer integrated type-specifiers, but that blow up `printf` even more. `"%zu"` for instance should better have followed the `inttypes.h` way. But C is not a synonym for consistency anyway.

Comment: A `printf()` alternative to `%016" PRIx64`: `printf("a is %016llx", a*1ull);`  Yet `PRIx64` is better even thought disjointed in the format.

Comment: @chux: Looks not less ugly, but it would at least be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a field width and zero padding flag to the `%llX` format specifier:

```
printf("a is %016llX b is %016llX c is %016llx" ,a, b, c);
```

The `16` says the field should be 16 characters wide (16 hex digits for a 64 bit number), and the leading `0` says that field should be padded on the left with zeros.

Also, `&&` is the logical AND operator.  The bitwise AND operator is `&`.

Comment: You are using the incorrect format strings. Correct would be to use `inttypes.h`, here `PRIx64`.

Comment: @Olaf Nah, just add `static_assert(sizeof(uint64_t)==sizeof(unsigned long long), "bleh")` in some header file. No need to spew PRI PRI PRI all over the code.

Comment: @Lundin: Why would I make my code generate a compile-time error just because I am too lazy to write it portable? If I compile on a platform which does not assert, I'll have to change it anyway, having to maintain two versions (`#ifdef` comes to mind ...).

Comment: I'm with @Lundin on this - the PRIxxx format specifiers are an ugly and overly verbose kludge and they tend to make code less readable.

Comment: I'm with @Olaf. Yes, they're ugly and boring to use; but there're some things that are even more.

Comment: @Olaf Because the format specifiers is a non-important trifle; what you really should be concerned about is the _type of each integer literal_ in your program. It is absolutely essential that you can guarantee which size each integer literal has. A programmer who tries to write portable programs and therefore have the integer literals change size whimsically between different systems will no doubt introduce numerous type-related bugs. And all such bugs tend to be very subtle, caused by implicit promotions and similar.

Comment: So when you get a compiler error, then there's usually a compiler option you can go set to state the size of int, long and long long - the size of integer literals will follow. And _that_ is how you ensure portability in a deterministic manner.

Comment: @Lundin: I'd appreciate if you can show me the options for gcc to set the size of `int`, etc. for ARM e.g. Until now, I was very sure, the AAPCS enforces specific sizes for them. As does POSIX (ILP32/I32LP64). For imposing a specific size: That depends. If you have specific requirements, e.g. a peripheral register, I agree. Otherwise a min. size is often sufficient (e.g. a loop-counter).

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure how to do that for GCC. It may be that the GCC port sets them at the point where the specific port is built, so probably not something that is easily tweaked ([this link suggests that some constants need to be set by the port](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gccint_112.html)). Other compilers that come with a GUI typically have some user-friendly option where you can easily change type sizes.

Comment: @Lundin: The sizes (and representation) of the standard types are target-specific with minimum ranges guaranteed by the standard. The actual representation is normally defined by the Procedure Call Standard and ABI of the target platform (CPU and OS (if any). Which compiler does allow to set the sizes for these types by an option? This is quite uncommon, maybe except for some 8-bit embedded compilers which allow to have 8-bit `int` (IIRC, Microchip for the PICs did allow this). But this is non--standard (`int` has a min. range of `+/-32767`).

Comment: @Olaf I've seen some flavour of this on many compilers. Not to set the size below the standard limits mind you (though some might indeed allow that too), but rather set size of int to 16 or 32, size of enum to 8 or 16, set size of long to 32 or 64 etc. Similarly, set signedness for char and enum, floating point standard etc. I think at least Mplab, Codewarrior and maybe Keil(?) allow this.

Comment: About `enum`: this is possible, as the standard leaves this to the compiler, **iff* all constants can be represented in the given type (so this setting would only be for the minimum type). But the constants still have to be `int` (one major reason `enum` is of little use to define constants). Signed-ness of `char` is left to the implementation anyway, but AAPCS requires `unsigned` (reason is likely ARMv4 had no sign-extend byte-load instructions). And for float the standard does not require a specific format, but only certain precision (`float` 6, `double` 10 decimal digits, etc.).

Comment: ARM AAPCS clearly defines the sizes for the standard integer types and `char` to be unsigned at least (too lazy to check for floating point). And many options (e.g. setting signed-ness of `char`) is just to get code working which relied on implementation defined behaviour. Actually this is an argument more to use `stdint`/`inttypes`.